# How to have a ListBox child item event not call parent event?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

**Problem**

When I click on a ListView item, it calls the "Tapped" event to navigate to another page. I have an Up Vote event within the ItemTemplate and when they call that specific event, I DO NOT want to call the ListView's tapped event. Any idea how I might do that?

**ListView XAML:**

Parent event, "listboxFeedbackItem_Tapped", occurs anytime any part of the listview is clicked

```
   <Grid x:Name="gridMainData" Grid.Row="2">
         <ProgressBar x:Name="prgBar" IsIndeterminate="True" VerticalAlignment="Top" Visibility="{Binding Path=FeedbackVM.IsLoading, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
          <ListView ItemTemplate="{StaticResource FeedbackTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding FeedbackVM.FeedbackCollection}" Tapped="listboxFeedbackItem_Tapped"/>
   </Grid>
```

**ItemTemplate Xaml:**

Event "UpVoteItem_Tap" should not trigger "listboxFeedbackItem_Tapped"

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="FeedbackTemplate">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Margin="0,0,30,0" Text="{Binding UpVotes}" Tapped="UpVoteItem_Tap"/>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Perhaps there's a method in C# to prevent subsequent events from occurring? 
Thanks, I'm still trying to wrap my head around XAML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you receive the UpVote tapped event, you can tell it not to pass the event to the parent listview by setting `e.Handled=true`:

```
void UpVoteItem_Tap(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Processing here
    ...

    // don't send event to parent
    e.Handled = true;
}
```